# jQuery Multiple Attribute Selector, Not Working :/

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selector

As far as I know, I'm following the correct usage form on: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/, but for whatever reason I'm not seeing, my code is not working.  Each attribute works fine independently of one another (i.e. 
`$(".tonight_stat_peopleThumbs li[srcid="+srcid+"]")` works and `$(".tonight_stat_peopleThumbs li[style*=inline-block]")` works) but they do not work together.

Here is my function in the JavaScript:

```
hidePatrons = function(srcid) {
    $(".tonight_stat_peopleThumbs li[srcid="+srcid+"][style*=inline-block]").each(function(){
        $(this).css({"display" : "none"});
    });
}
```

Here is a piece from the HTML:

```
<ul activepage="1" class="tonight_stat_peopleThumbs" style="width:171px">
  <li id="myid" class="myclass" ptype="people" ptime="11101101" style="display:inline-block;">
    <a href="http://domain.com/users/#.php">
      <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/#/picture" />
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

NOTE: The '#' are inserted for privacy, assume they are fbid numbers.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that while [CSS allows attribute selectors without quotes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors), there are quotes in every [jQuery example](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). My experience has been that jQuery does not select reliably without quotes.

```
/* Good for CSS, bad for jQuery */
[foo=bar]

/* Good for both */
[foo="bar"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('.tonight_stat_peopleThumbs li[srcid="' + srcid + '"][style*="inline-block"]')
```

- mind the quoting!

Answer (score 0):

try changing `li[srcid="+srcid+"]` to `li[id="+srcid+"]` I don't see a "srcid" attribute so I assume you are looking to search on the "id" attribute

Answer (score 0):

can you please try like this way? the following is working fine for me for your HTML code.

```
 hidePatrons = function(srcid) {
        $("#tonight_stat_peopleThumbs li[ptype=people][style*=inline-block]").each(function(){
            $(this).css({"display" : "none"});
        });
    }
```

**note**: **#** is for id, and **.** is for class. I changed **.** to **#** and **srcid="+srcid+"** to **ptype=people** from your code.

Comment: That was a typo on my part; I have a sandbox and a live, put the wrong one on here, changed it in my above though, thanks for the catch! :)